# regex for parsing variable names

Tags: regex

I am trying to get the variable names and store it in a list, but I am having trouble with coming up the regex.  So, I have a file with lines like below:

```
float func(float a, float b, float c)
{
   float i, j,           k;
   float2 w;
}
```

and what I would like to do is to get the name of the function along with the parameters var and local var.  So, I want my regex to return `func` `a` `b` `c` `i` `j` `k` `w`

and my current regex is `\bfloat*\d* +\w*\b`

which finds `float func` `float a` `float b` `float c` `float i` `float w`.  I am not sure how to separate the float part and only take the var name with regex (I suppose I can use capture groups) but I'm not sure what to do when there are multiple var names on the same line.  Also, I'm only interested in variables that are of float types.  Any tip would be helpful.

**EDITED**
I just came up with this regex `\bfloat*\d* +\w*[ *,* *\w]*\b`, which matches what I need but can I get the names in groups with just a single regex?

Comment: Regular expressions aren't a very reliable way to parse code.  If you still want to use them, any chance you are using .NET or another regex implementation that supports variable length lookbehinds?  Without them it will be difficult if not impossible to do this in a single regex.

Comment: nop ;/ I'm just doing this in python with the re module.  But I just edited my post with the new regex, could you see if there's any problem with it by any chance?

Comment: This is as close I could get to it `float2?\s+(\w+)(?:,\s*(?!float)(\w+)\s*)*` testing it in [RegexHero](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=10211ce7-d283-4a6e-ae4d-3ebfb199941d) but the issue is it will not capture `j` because I am using a repeated capture group which overrides matches everytime it finds a new match hence `j` gets overrriden with `k`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you could do this in two steps, since I am pretty sure doing it in a single regex isn't possible:

```
import re

data = '''float func(float a, float b, float c)
{
   float i, j,           k;
   float2 w;
   float a, int b;
}'''
regex = re.compile(r'\bfloat2?\s+(\w+(?:,\s*(?!\w+\s+\w+)\w+)*)')
var_list = []
for vars in regex.findall(data):
    vars = (v.strip() for v in vars.split(','))
    var_list.extend((v for v in vars if v))

print var_list
# ['func', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'w', 'a']
```

This uses only a minor change to your regex, so that the capture group contains all comma separated `float` values, then in the `for` loop we split the comma separate values and add them to the result list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But what if the input data is ``float a, int b;`` ? It will also catch ``int`` as var name

Comment: @overloading - See my edit, should work properly for that case now.  Note that regular expressions are still a bad way to parse arbitrary code.

Comment: Thanks, could you explain what ``?:`` does?  Also, I tested your regex with a regexr builder online and it works for cases with a line break after the variable, like ``float a,    //space and \n here   b;`` and parses a and b even though theres a new line and spaces between a and b.  But when I tested it in python with the same regex, it will only catch ``a`` but not ``b``, do you know why by any chance?

Comment: `?:` makes the group non-capturing, which is important here since `re.findall()` would return a tuple of the groups.  I'm not sure why the regexr behavior is different, but maybe instead of `\s` you should use `[ \t]`, because `\s` will match newlines which probably isn't necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I got it to match properly now.  I have a question following this problem.  Since now it matches variables with linebreaks inbetween them, is it possible to replace those linebreaks with space or empty string using the re.sub function?  if so, do you do it with capture groups?

Comment: The easiest way to do this would be to use the exact same pattern for `re.sub`, and use a function for the replacement (see [docs on `re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub)).  You could probably use `lambda m: m.group(0).replace('\n', ' ')`.

Comment: I have another quick question. I have it matches every type of float and int, but I dont want to match when theres an unsigned int, so something like the this would not match ``unsigned int a;``.  I tried to do it with a negative lookbehind, my regex looks like this ``\b((?:float|(?<!unsigned\s)int)\d*\*?\s+\*?\s*\w+(?:\s*,\s*\*?\s*(?!\w+\s*\*?\s+\w+)\w+)*)``  it works for matching except unsigned int, but I am wondering why I cannot put a ``*`` or ``+`` after ``\s`` in the lookbehind?  So here, ``(?<!unsigned\s+)``,if I do that it will simply not match anything, and I can't figure out why

Comment: @overloading Many regex implementations do not support variable length lookbehinds, it is a fairly common limitation.